# Installing detectron2 in Heroku

Tags: python, torch

RROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement detectron2>=0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_345e2e66/requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: none)

```
   ERROR: No matching distribution found for detectron2>=0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_345e2e66/requirements.txt (line 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use pip freeze, it will not work
just add these in your req.txt

1. -f https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cpu/torch1.8/index.html
2. detectron2

then it will successfully install your detectron

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work on Linux only. To make it work on Mac:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
```

Then add

> -e detectron2

to your requirements.txt

Source: https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html